Getting Real Date and Time in Excel VBA if System time is on Manual
if a User has altered the System Time, the Date and Now functions return the ALTERED time. How to override this and still get the Real System time?
While using this code, I can't use Internet, Powershell or anything outside VBA.
Tried kernel 32 Functions but failed to break through. Any help will be highly appreciated.

If the system time is set at low level ie Bios, then that will be the time. Unless you can get to the net and find one of the control clock feeds.

Sorry, while executing this code, I can't use Internet.

Using only a QueryTable object (and assuming you can access the internet) and no other objects, you could retrieve the local time in cell A97 if you update the URL in this answer to use timeanddate.com (you won't need the 2nd half of the procedure).
